# website got blacklisted by google and most of the anti virus company

Tags: malware, blacklist

i just scan my website by sitecheck.sucuri.net

```
Status: Site Potentially Harmful. Immediate Action is Required.
Web Trust:  Blacklisted (10 Blacklists Checked): Indicates that a major security company (such as Google, McAfee, Norton, etc) is blocking access to your website for security reasons. Please see our recommendation below to fix this issue and restore your traffic.
Scan    Result  Severity    Recommendation
Website Blacklisting    Detected    Critical    CLEAN UP Clean Up & Remove Blacklisting
Site Likely Compromised Detected    Critical    CLEAN UP Clean Up & Remove Blacklisting
Website Firewall    Not Found   Medium Risk PATCH AND PROTECT With Sucuri Firewall
```

anythings i can do for retrieve my website back?

Comment: You need to tell us more about your site such as OS, web server, CMS, database, FTP, SMTP, DNS, etc. for anything that is installed. Otherwise, how are we to even guess??

Comment: it should be a linux, a drupal site. If i delete all compromised file, how can i make google, and other anti-virus brand to remove the blacklist

Comment: Update all software immediately. Check all user accounts and reset passwords removing usernames that may have been added by a hacker. Run an anti-virus including rootkit on the hard-drive - you can use ClamAV for this. Check any plug-ins and themes for vulnerabilities as well as all software here: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 You may need to restore files and data from a backup. Check your sites files carefully. This is not a quick fix. You need to go slow and be detailed. Cheers!!

Comment: i don't have control for the web server

Comment: If there are more than one site hosted on a server, it is possible that one vulnerable site effects the others. If you do not have access to the server, then your webhost ***must*** help you clean this up for it's own sake. If you have trouble, then it may be time to look for another webhost.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an account with Google's web master tool and ask that they review your page again.

I would suggest that before you do, you scan your site for malware before hand and remove any plugins that you suspect may be the culprit.

Comment: any tools i can scan the website which will shows the which files got compromised?

Comment: You can run your website through here - ](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net)

Comment: @SamanthaStultz He did already. ;-)

Comment: @closetnoc my bad. Bad attention to detail on my part. Ha!

Comment: @SamanthaStultz I have done it too!! We are all human of course except for me... I am part poodle and something reptilian.